# SSH access to a ubuntu box with no terminal

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, terminal, putty

Trying to figure out a way so that when i have somebody PUTTY into my linux ubuntu box, they will have no terminal access. Basically i just want them to have access to some repos for SVN but when they ssh, they should have no options for command lines.

Comment: Probably better on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 4):

Set their shell to `/bin/false`.

Comment: usermod -s /bin/false username

Answer (score 0):

You could probably put something like this in your sshd_config:

```
Match User theusername
ForceCommand svnserve -t
```